# Get the command line in full, of a GUI program

Tags: launcher, process

How to know the complete command line used to invoke a GUI program currently running ?

tried `ps -e`, only put its filename

Comment: Does `ps -e -O cmd` output what you want?

Answer (score 1):

`man` (for reference MANnuals) is usually setup by default so for most commands you can do for example `man ps` to get the manual for the `ps` command. There you will see one of the (many) options is -f for a "full-format" listing so:

`ps -ef`

Comment: This is neater than formatting the output for `ps` with `-O` for OP purpose. +1

Answer (score 0):

you can always use htop

```
apt install htop
```

then use F5 to tree view and use F3 to search for the program by name
you can see the bin that's used